# Download dynamic file with GWT

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, rpc

I have a GWT page where user enter data (start date, end date, etc.), then this data goes to the server via RPC call. On the server I want to generate Excel report with POI and let user save that file on their local machine.

This is my test code to stream file back to the client but for some reason I think it does not know how to stream file to the client when I'm using RPC:

```
public class ReportsServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements ReportsService {
    public String myMethod(String s) {

        File f = new File("/excelTestFile.xls");

        String filename = f.getName();

        int length = 0;

        try {
            HttpServletResponse resp = getThreadLocalResponse();
            ServletOutputStream op = resp.getOutputStream();
            ServletContext context = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
            resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            resp.setContentLength((int) f.length());
            resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*=\"utf-8''" + filename + "");

            byte[] bbuf = new byte[1024];
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));

            while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
                op.write(bbuf, 0, length);
            }

            in.close();
            op.flush();
            op.close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Server says: " + filename;
    }
}
```

I've read somewhere on internet that you can't do file stream with RPC and I have to use Servlet for that. Is there any example of how to use Servlet and how to call that servlet from **ReportsServiceImpl**. Do I really need to make a servlet or it is possible to stream it back with my RPC?

Comment: Please elaborate the problem in more detail. "it does not know" is not really descriptive. What exactly happens? What exactly happens not?

Comment: The answer of @sri makes sense. Now it's my turn to post some comments: 1) `DataInputStream` is superflous. Just use straight `FileInputStream`. You after all *only* need the `read()` method definied in `InputStream` class. 2) The `in != null` check is superflous as well since that's **never** null (you created new one using `new`, that can never be null). 3) `Content-Disposition` header looks malformed in the `filename` part. To get some ideas how to do the *basic* file serving, you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html) useful. Good luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to make a regular Servlet, you *cannot* stream binary data from `ReportsServiceImpl`. Also, there is no way to call the servlet from ReportsServiceImpl - your client code has to directly invoke the servlet.

On the client side, you'd have to create a normal anchor link with the parameters passed via the query string. Something like `<a href="http://myserver.com/myservlet?parm1=value1&.."</a>`.

On the server side, move your code to a standard Servlet, one that does NOT inherit from `RemoteServiceServlet`. Read the parameters from the request object, create the excel and send it back to the client. The browser will automatically popup the file download dialog box.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that just using GWT RPC and [Data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI):

1. In your example, make your `myMethod` return the file content.
2. On the client side, format a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI) with the file content received.
3. Use `Window.open` to open a file save dialog passing the formatted [DataURI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI).

Take a look at this reference, to understand the [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI) usage:

> [Export to csv in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639372/export-to-csv-in-jquery/7588465#7588465)

Comment: Need to be consider that DATA URIs are not supported on IE 6 & 7. IE8 has partial support though.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get the binary data you want back through the RPC channel in a number of ways... uuencode, for instance.  However, you would still have to get the browser to handle the file as a download.

And, based on your code, it appears that you are trying to trigger the standard browser mechanism for handling the given mime-type by modifying the response in the server so the browser will recognize it as a download... open a save dialog, for instance. To do that, you need to get the browser to make the request for you and you need the servlet there to handle the request. It can be done with rest urls, but ultimately you will need a serviet to do even that.

You need, in effect, to set a browser window URL to the URL that sends back the modified response object.

So this question (about streaming) is not really compatible with the code sample. One or the other (communication protocols or server-modified response object) approach has to be adjusted.

The easiest one to adjust is the communication method.